# Server connection to allow a client to specify a file server and displayed in a JTextArea

Tags: java

Okay, I'm having issues with this one, the code compiles and displays the `JTextField` GUI box with errors.

I'm getting these error codes:

```
*java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:55)
    at ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:7)*
```

I'm suppose to:

retrieve as many files on the Client side as you like by typing the name of a file in the JTextField and hitting return. The Client should make a connection with the Server ONLY when the user types a file name in the JTextField and hits return. It should close that connection the moment the file is retrieved from the Server.

The server should operate in an infinite loop waiting for more connections.
The server should use port #8189.

Here's my **Client** class

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private JTextField enterField; // text field to accept input from user
   private JTextArea displayArea; // display area to display information from user
   private Scanner  input; // input from user
   private Formatter output; // output to server
   private Socket connection; // connection to server
   private JPanel panel; // panel to hold components
   private JLabel label; // label to prompt user
   private JScrollPane scroller; // scroller for text area


   // set up GUI, connect to server, and get streams
   public Client()
   {
     label = new JLabel ( " Enter the FILE NAME to retrieve: ");
     panel = new JPanel(); // create panel
     panel.setLayout ( new GridLayout (1, 2, 0, 0));
     panel.add( label ); // add label to panel
     enterField = new JTextField(); // create text field
     enterField.addActionListener( this ); // add action listener
     panel.add( enterField ); // add text area to panel
     displayArea = new JTextArea(); // add text area
     scroller = new JScrollPane( displayArea ); // add scrolling
     setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // set layout of JFrame
     add( panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // add panel  to north
     add( scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER); // add scrolling text area to center

     try // connect to server, get streams
     {
         // create socket to make connection to server
         connection = new Socket( InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 7985 );
         // local host address and port identical to server port number
         output = new Formatter(connection.getOutputStream()); // output stream to server
         output.flush(); // flush output to server
         input = new Scanner( connection.getInputStream() ); // input stream from server
     } // end try
     catch( IOException ioexception)
     {
         ioexception.printStackTrace();
     } // end catch

      setSize(400, 200);  // set size of window
      setVisible( true ); // show window
   } // end client constructor


   // process file name entered by client
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       try      // display contents of file
       {
           String fileName  = event.getActionCommand() + "\n";
           output.format( fileName ); // put file name in stream
           output.flush(); // send to server
           String inputLine = input.nextLine(); // read response from server
           displayArea.setText( inputLine ); // show response line in text area

           // if file  exists,  display file contents
           if (inputLine.equals( "The file contains:"))
           {
               while ( input.hasNextLine() ) // read new line
               {
                   inputLine = input.nextLine(); // read response from server
                   displayArea.append(inputLine + "\n"); // add line to text area
               } // end while
           } // end if

           enterField.setEditable( true ); // enable editing of enterfield
           enterField.setBackground( Color.red ); // set color
       } // end try
       finally
       {
           try
           {
             input.close();       // close input
             output.close();      // close output
             connection.close();  // close connection
           } // end try
           catch (IOException ioexception)
           {
               ioexception.printStackTrace();
               System.exit(1);
           } // end catch

       } // end finally
    } // end Client class
} // end class Client
```

Here's my **Server** class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Server extends JFrame
{

   private Formatter output; // output stream to client
   private Scanner input; // input stream from client
   private ServerSocket server; // server socket
   private Socket connection; // connection to client

   // set up GUI
   public Server()
   {
       try
       {
            server = new ServerSocket( 7985, 10 ); // create ServerSocket
            // first parameter is port
            // second is how many clients server can queue
       } // end try
       catch (IOException exception)
       {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
       } // end catch

   } // end Server constructor

   // set up and run server
   public void runServer()
   {
      try // set up server to receive connections; process connections
      {
         connection = server.accept();
         output = new Formatter(connection.getOutputStream()); // output stream for socket
         output.flush();                                       // flush output stream
         input = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());     // input stream for socket
         File inputFile = new File(input.nextLine());          // get file name from client
         String result;                                        // result variable for

         if ( inputFile.exists())
         {
             Scanner fileInput = new Scanner( inputFile );
             output.format("The file contains:" );
             output.flush();                    // send to client

             while (fileInput.hasNextLine() )   // while there are more lines in the file
             {
                 result = fileInput.nextLine(); // read a line from the file
                 output.format( result ); // output line of file  **PROBLEM HERE**
                 output.flush();                // send to client
             } // end while
         } // end if
         else
         {
             result = inputFile.getName() + " does not exist! \n";
             output.format( result );       // inform client the file does not exist
             output.flush();                //send to client
         } // end else
      } // end try
      catch (IOException ioException)
      {
         ioException.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(0);
      } //  end catch
      finally
      {
          try
          {
              output.close();       // close output
              input.close();        // close input
              connection.close();   //close connection
          } // end try
          catch (IOException ioException)
          {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
          } //  end catch
      } // end finally
    } // end runServer method
}
```

These are my test classes:

**ClientTest**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ClientTest
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Client application = new Client(); // create client application
      application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
   } // end main
} // end class ClientTest
```

**ServerTest**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ServerTest
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Server application = new Server(); // create server
      application.runServer(); // run server application
   } // end main
} // end class ServerTest
```

Comment: "Connection refused" sounds like firewall issues, or no one is listening on the port you specified.

Comment: My firewall is disabled and the port is open. What else can I do?

Comment: What about the sever side?

Comment: The server wasn't running, or had exited somehow. It's improperly written to only accept one connection, after all. Not a firewall issue. @markspace Firewalls cause connection timeouts, not refusals. A refusal would be an information leak: the host exists.

Comment: Not the problem but your description says The server should use port #8189, but the code uses port 7985

Comment: Your server will only accept one client. Generally this is not the way servers are written. As it is everytime you start the client you will need to first restart the server, if you are not doing that it would cause a connection refused.

Comment: To run the program correctly, first run the ServerTest class. Once the server is running, run the Client test class. In the text field, enter Music.txt and press enter. I am running Netbeans IDE

Comment: And how can I go about combing my main classes and test classes into one?

Comment: I am new to using servers but any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakes I've found in your code:

1-As pointed out by WillShackleford and other commenters, the server receives on connection *just once*, and then ends. Servers usually are accepting connections within a loop. As simple as this:

```
while(true)
{
    Socket connection=server.accept();
    process(connection);
}
```

In this way, the server is working endlessly until it is abruptly killed (by pressing CTRL+C or CTRL+Z by command-line). A further improvement may include some mechanism to make it end gracefully. For example, a special message recived from a client.

(Another nice improvement would be the server being able to process multiple requests simultaneously, by starting the method `process` in a *new Thread*.)

2-The client starts a connection from the very constructor, and without sending any filename. I think it is clearly a bug, because it should wait until the user efectively enters a filename and hits return. You'd better drop that connection off.

3-A minor drawback you have already spotted is that sometimes happens an `IllegalFormatException` in this line of `Server`:

```
output.format( result );
```

The reason is that strings accepted by `output.format` must be *properly composed* according to the specification of [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). So, if your file contains some characters like "%", the formatter would consideer them special, and won't print them properly. In fact, it may produce errors.

If you want to fix this, you have to give up using `Formatter` and replace it by the very `OutputStream` returned by the socket, which may be as useful, too. But if it is not a big problem, just consideer it a *limitation* of your application, so take it into account when doing tests.

Another good practices you could use:

- Do not mix APIs: The server is not user-interactive, so it must not extend `JPanel` nor have any dependencies of swing.
- Do not repeat the same values in the code. The *port number* should be received by input parameter in `Server` and `Client`, so you can specify them both from the same party (the script that starts both testers).
- Too many calls to `flush`. This is useful to make sure that no data remains in the buffer without being sent. In your application, the cycle of an outputstream/formatter is *atomic*: it is open, used and closed without delaying. So I guess you could get rid of all of them flushes.
- Too many `catch`es makes your code difficult to read. My recomendation is that all methods should declare `IOException` in its `throws` clause, and process it at the most upper level in the application as possible: In the client, at the end of `actionPerformed`. In the server, at the end of `process` method.
  And do not call `System.exit` just because there has been a circumstantial error. If the error does not prevent the program for sending/receiving new requests, just print the error at the console, and let the execution go on.
- A better tracing would be useful, too. Add traces in the server to report every interesting event: When the server is listening in a port, when a  request has been received, when it has been successfully processed, and of corse, when some error has happened.

Comment: Much appreciated. I will use this as a guide and see what I can use and should change. Thanks